# $setPristine() not working.

Tags: angularjs

**** Note I cut out some of my other functions so that the code could be read through faster.  I cannot clear the form. when i click the button with the cancel function.  I thought I could set a default form, but this doesn't make a difference.

```
<form  name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()"> 
    <table class="mealCost"> 

        <!-- descriptions -->
        <tr> 
            <td> Base Meal Price: </td>
            <td><input type="number" name="price" ng-model="mealPrice" required></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- waiter puts in the info -->
        <tr> 
            <td> Tax Rate: % </td>
            <td><input type="number" step="0.01" name="tax" ng-model="mealTax" required></td>

        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td> Tip Percentage: % </td>
            <td><input type="number"  name="tip" step="0.01" ng-model="tipPercent" required></td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <p class="userResponse"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    <!-- <input id="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" ng-submit="cancel(original)"> -->
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Start Over</button>
    </p>

</form>
```

Here is my javascript  I am trying to set my form to $setPristine using the button command wiht ng-click.  I though that setting a default form would help but nothing happens on submit

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]).
    controller('costController', function($scope) {
        // $scope.ready= false;
        $scope.mealPrice ="" ;
        $scope.mealTax = 0.05;
        $scope.tipPercent =0.05; 
        //  possibly could do 

        var defaultForm={
            price: "",
            tax: "",
            tip:""
        }

$scope.cancel = function() {
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);
            console.log('empty');
        }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're using it wrong.

$setPristine:

"This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form."

So this only clears classes but not the $scope variables.
You do reset a $scope.user variable, could say:

**Add 'user.' in front of every model in the Html**

```
ng-model="user.tipPercent"
ng-model="user.mealTax"
ng-model="user.mealPrice"
```

And replace this in your JS:

```
// $scope.ready= false;
$scope.mealPrice ="" ;
$scope.mealTax = 0.05;
$scope.tipPercent =0.05; 
//  possibly could do 

var defaultForm={
    price: "",
    tax: "",
    tip:""
}

$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);
    console.log('empty');
}
```

to this:

```
var defaultForm = {
    mealPrice : "",
    mealTax : 0.05,
    tipPercent : 0.05
}

$scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);
    console.log('empty');
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks Jason.  I had edited this a dozen times and came close.  Adding user.  fixed it!

Comment: I followed above explain example but every time getting "ERROR: Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.ContactForm.$setPristine')"

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.master = {};

$scope.reset = function(form) {

      if (form) {
          form.$setPristine();
           $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
         form.$setUntouched();
      }
```

Comment: It would really improve your answer if you added some words of explanation, perhaps a link to some related documentation as well. The person asking this question, and any other person who reads this in the future, will have no way to tell if your solution works without copy/pasting random code and running it. That's never a good idea. Explain what this does, why it does it, and why it is related to the problem. Explain why this is better or different than the answer that was accepted 6 months ago.

Comment: The form is displayed in Bootstrap Modal. So every time I show it I reset the model. However if I tried to save the empty form, get errors and I close the modal and reopen it, the errors were not getting cleared. Most of the times the error display in the form is coupled with formName.fieldName.touched == true. So just setting form.$setUntouched() did the trick for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would work if the `ng-model` were bound to `$scope.user.price`, `$scope.user.tax` and `$scope.user.tip`. However, they are bound to `$scope.price`, `$scope.tax` and `$scope.tip`.

Setting the form `$pristine` only marks the values as not modified by user. It doesn't actually change the values.

**Solution A:**

Bind the models to `user.*` and replace

```
$scope.mealPrice = '';
$scope.mealTax = 0.05;
$scope.tipPercent = 0.05;
```

with

```
$scope.user = {
    mealPrice: '',
    mealTax: 0.05,
    tipPercent: 0.05
};
```

**Solution B:**

Replace:

```
$scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);
```

with

```
$scope.mealPrice = defaultFrom.mealPrice;
$scope.mealTax = defaultFrom.mealTax;
$scope.tipPercent = defaultFrom.tipPercent;
```