# while resetting the field values, the form is not getting to the initial state

Tags: angularjs

I am clearing all the fields when reset button is clicked. However the form state is not being set to initial state. There is some error. I am changing the color of the text if it is ng-valid or ng-invalid. Once the field values are reset how to bring the form to the initial state.

**HTML Code**

```
    <style>
    input.ng-invalid {
            border: 1px solid #FCD8C8;

        }
        input.ng-valid {
            border: 1px solid  #B3F7BC;
            background-color: #E7F2E9;
        }

    </style>
<div ng-controller="DBController">
        <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;aligh:right;float:right">
                <button >Save</button>
                <button ng-click="resetDashboard()">Reset </button>
            </div>


        <form name="DashboardForm" ng-model="DashboardForm" novalidate class="css-form">
        <br>

        <p>Title:   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="dashboard.title" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20">
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="DashboardForm.title.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="DashboardForm.title.$error.required">required.</span>
        <span ng-show="DashboardForm.title.$error.minlength">Title is too short.</span> 
        <span ng-show="DashboardForm.title.$error.maxlength">Title is too long.</span>  
        </span>

        <br>

        <p>Description: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="textarea" style="border-radius:3px;width:300px;height:30px" name="description" ng-model="dashboard.description"  ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="1050" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="DashboardForm.description.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="DashboardForm.description.$error.required">required.</span>
            <span ng-show="DashboardForm.description.$error.minlength">Description is too short.</span> 
            <span ng-show="DashboardForm.description.$error.maxlength">Description is too long.</span>  
        </span>
        </p>

        </form>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
    ;(function() {
        "use strict";
         angular.module('App')
        .controller('DBController', ['$scope', '$log','$window', 
                                        function($scope, $log,window) {

            $scope.title = null;
            $scope.description = null;

            var defaultdashboardForm = {
                  title : "",
                  description : ""
              };

            $scope.resetDashboard = function()
            {
                $scope.dashboard.title='';
                $scope.dashboard.description='';
            }

        }]);
    })();
```

[**Problem Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/j72Byfx4iRmByj8li5Rz?p=preview)

Comment: That is because you have use `ng-minlength` which is not adding value inside your `ng-model` ..Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28338146/2435473 will give you idea what is going on behind the scene

Comment: thanks pankaj. now how do i clear a value but still is valid. I had set as null. Why was this not happening when the form is loaded. At that time there was no value assigned to the textbox.

Comment: Have you read my answer thoroughly...then only you will come to know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your approach doesn't work. you could find that answer with [**Explanation here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338146/2435473)

You could solve this do this doing some sort of hack. Before clearing value of ng-model value make them valid and then clear out the value of `ng-model`

```
$scope.resetDashboard = function() {
    //make field valid so that that gets filled into the ng-model & we can clear it.
    $scope.DashboardForm.title.$setValidity('minlength', false)
    $scope.DashboardForm.description.$setValidity('minlength', false)
    $scope.dashboard.title = '';
    $scope.dashboard.description = '';
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JENIvQg2nslW6BCVylnE?p=preview)

Comment: thanks pushkar. i got a wonderful answer on how to resolve this from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191744/setpristine-not-working. I tried it and it is working fine. the scope varaibles had to be reset once the  ng-dirty class is reset with pristine state.

Comment: You could accept mine answer if it does work..bdw I'm Pankaj not pushkar

Comment: got confused with parkar to pushkar... apologies pankaj.

Comment: @user2010243 no probs..Glad to help you..THanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `$scope.DashboardForm.$setPristine(true)`?

[$setPristine](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine)

Comment: i tried that. What i would want is the backcolor of the text boxes should be set to white as it was when the form is loaded. Now there is a color added to the input text boxes which is not getting removed.