# Angularjs + Disable and Enable submit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have sample code like this:

Html Code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <input name="myText" type="text" name="test" ng-model="mytext" required />
      <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Js code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.save = function(){
    //logic or http method
    console.log("Test");
  }
});
```

Attached the code in this link: [Click Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8eIGjKQapI7mpZmFIxr?p=preview)

Logic:

1. Default save button disabled.
2. After enter the form enable the button.
3. After save again disable the save button.
4. Again user enter the text need to enable save button.

Note: Here I attached only one input but I have multiple input fields.
Also, In save function I had logic data save into database.

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Comment: you ned to check if the form is dirty and that is easy (myForm.$dirty) and then you set the form to pristine in your save()-function, but your $scope will mess things up, so you need to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191744/setpristine-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$pristine` to identify if there were any changes to the form and enable button only then:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <input name="myText" type="text" name="test" ng-model="mytext" required />
        <button ng-click="save(myForm)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pristine">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Notice how `$pristine` is used on `ng-disabled`:

```
ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || myForm.$pristine"
```

In this case button will be disabled if form is invalid or if there were no changes to the form.

If you use this approach you also need to set the form to pristine after saving the data. You can use method `$setPristine`:

```
$scope.save = function(myForm) {
    // set form to pristine
    myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Notice that there is a form parameter which is used to pass a form to the method. In HTML you also need to pass this parameter as part of `ng-click`:

```
ng-click="save(myForm)"
```

Here is [JSFiddle that demonstrates the functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/12drw3go/)

For more information check out [documentation of FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Answer (score 0):

you have disabled the submit button when the form is invalid.

```
myForm.$invalid
```

so whenever a required field is blank the form will be invalid and button will be disabled. As soon as all the required input in the form have values, submit button will be enabled.

To make it disabled you need to reset all the modal variables of the required  inputs once the save has done its work i.e on the success call back of http request reset the model  variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is how i would do it, i'll add another tracking variable. something like this.

```
$scope.btnStatus = true;
  $scope.save = function(){
    //logic or http method
    $scope.btnStatus = false;
    console.log("Test");
  }
  $scope.onChange = function(){

    if($scope.btnStatus == false)
      $scope.btnStatus = true;
  }
```

and the html would look like this.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myText" type="text" name="test" ng-change="onChange()" ng-model="mytext" required /> 
  <button ng-click="save()"  ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || !btnStatus">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is a working [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/YL9ki5Uy9A9VPauchwjg?p=preview) based off of your code.

Comment: using $pristine is better, no need for more variables or functions

Comment: @JohanBlomgren just because there are a better ways to do that, that doesn't mean i deserve a down vote.  Thanks anyway